# can't change text area style to field_with_error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm dealing with this legacy form for creating a new conversation. It has two fields : Name and description (the first comment of a conversation)

Here are the fields :
`_fields.haml`

```
.conversation_title= f.label :name, t('.name')
.clear
= f.text_field :name, :style => 'width: 230px'
= errors_for f.object, :name

if f.object.new_record?
  = f.fields_for :comments, f.object.comments.build do |comment_fields|
    .conversation_title= comment_fields.label :description, t('.description')
    = comment_fields.text_area :body, :placeholder => t("comments.new.conversation"),    :style => 'width: 545px'
    = errors_for f.object, :comments
```

from the `new` view for conversations

```
= form_for [@current_project, @conversation], :html => { 'data-project-id' => @current_project.id, :name => 'form_new_conversation', :multipart => true } do |f| #, :onsubmit => 'return validate_form_new_conversation(form_new_conversation)'
  = render 'fields', :f => f, :project => @current_project
  = render 'watcher_fields', :f => f, :project => @current_project
```

The associated validations are :

`conversation.rb`

```
validates_presence_of :name, :message => :no_title, :unless => :simple?
validates_presence_of :comments, :message => :must_have_one, :unless => :is_importing
```

`comment.rb`

```
validates_presence_of :body, :unless => lambda { |c| c.task_comment? or c.uploads.to_a.any? or c.google_docs.any? }
```

For some reason, the proc associated to fields with error from `base.rb`

```
@@field_error_proc = Proc.new{ |html_tag, instance| "<div class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe }
```

doesn't get called for the text area, so it doesn't change its style to make it turn red. It does for the `:name` field. Error messages get displayed properly

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The validation would be for the `Comment` model (rather than the `Conversation` model) on the `body` field.  Check to make sure that validation exists.  You can debug this to make sure that `comment_fields.object` has an error set on the `body` field, too.

Comment: I've added the validation on the `Comment`model in the description of my problem. On debugging, it is made clear that the comment_fields.object has no error. So the message that is displayed on under the comment body field corresponds to the validation on conversation. Debugging also reveals that the same validations are called several times. Is this normal?

Comment: @arthur I would not be surprised if validations were triggered multiple times in a situation with nested forms.  I would try to avoid it, but it would not be my biggest concern.  Also, I doubt that it is the cause of any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I failed to notice one important part of this line in your code:

```
= f.fields_for :comments, f.object.comments.build do |comment_fields|
```

You call `f.object.comments.build` which means that you will always end up with a new instance of `Comment` (rather than the instance that was validated in the controller).

To avoid this you can build a comment in the controller.  If you are using the normal restful actions you probably have two places where you want to build a comment.  First in the `new` action and second, in the `create` action.

```
def new
  @conversation = Conversation.new
  @conversation.comments.build # Create a blank comment so that the fields will be shown on the form
end

def create
  @conversation = Conversation.new(params[:conversation])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @conversation.save
      format.html { redirect_to conversations_path }
    else
      format.html {
        @conversation.comments.build if @conversation.comments.blank? # Create a blank comment only if none exists
        render :action => "new"
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: removing f.object.comments.build and having the comment built in the conversations controller makes the errors "no subject" and "no body" appear at the same time, while they would only appear one at a time before. Seems that there is still no error on the body field of the comment, despite the validation.

Comment: @arthur it seems logical to me that both subject and body errors are show if both errors are present.  I'm a bit confused about the missing comment body error.  You say a "no body" error message is shown, which sounds like the error is indeed present.  I must be missing something important.